# Scala passing class type as an argument

Tags: scala, function, class, parameters

Hey I'm trying to write below code in best possible way in scala, please help me if there is a better way!

```
public final <T> T deserialize(String jsonString, Class<T> klass) {
    try {
        return objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, klass);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("Failed to deserialize {} to class {}, {}", jsonString, klass, e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Is below a good one?

```
  def deserialize[T: Manifest](value: String): T = {
    mapper.readValue(value, typeReference[T])
  }
```

Comment: `Manifest` is deprecated. Use `TypeTag`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to obtain a `Class[T]`, use `scala.reflect.ClassTag` (not `TypeTag`; you can get the `Class` from it, but only in a round-about way):

```
def deserialize[T](value: String)(implicit tag: ClassTag[T]): T = {
  mapper.readValue(value, tag.runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[T]])
}
```

Be careful not to forget the type parameter when calling (i.e. `deserialize[String]("\"a\"")`, not `deserialize("\"a\"")`), or Scala will infer it to be `Nothing`.

It's also possible you'll need to pass boxed classes instead of primitives (e.g. `deserialize[java.lang.Integer]("1")`), if so you can fix the problem but this will require extra code.